# How to use loop for column vectors in dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
example <- data.frame(tree=c(25,24,6,57,47), weed=c(4,66,88,9,6), plant=c(47,5,6,9,6), shrub=c(23,7,8,9,3))
```

I want the same result, which gave the following functions:

```
colMeans(example)
boxplot(example)
```

but it is important to me using loop. I have tried these:

```
for(i in 1:length(colnames(example))){
print(mean(i))
}

par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for(i in 1:length(colnames(example))){
print(boxplot(i))
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: `sapply(example, mean)` will help you to get col means.

Comment: `print(mean(example[[i]]))` and `print(boxplot(example[[i]]))`.

Comment: Also `1:length(colnames(example))` is the same as `1:ncol(example)` or `seq_along(example)`.

Comment: In your code, `i` is a numeric value, not a column. Therefor, `mean(i)` will be `i` . And as @Jilber said, using the apply family functions will accelerate the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
for(i in 1:ncol(example)){
     print(mean(example[,i]))
 }
```